# ReactJS and MDL menu not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-design-lite

Trying to make an app that uses Material Design Lite. However, I've encountered a problem where MDL menu just won't open.

[Check this pen](http://codepen.io/Enki/pen/KMaGPa)

I also have tried following [this article](http://quaintous.com/2015/07/09/react-components-with-mdl/), which describes that React and MDL don't play along nicely and it is needed to call `componentHandler` to upgrade elements. But in this pen components are not dynamically loaded, so they should be updated automatically.

Looking forward to hearing your answers, thanks!

Comment: There are actually a couple of reasons why React and MDL don't play nicely.  The problem you're experiencing is that React will delegate all events to the document body, and it will use a SyntheticEvent in place of a browser's native event for compatibility reasons ([more info here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html)).  In short, when an event is fired on your component, **your component will be the last to hear of it**, so the upgraded MDL component isn't receiving a click event.  I don't have a solution for you, but perhaps this information can help you find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use htmlFor instead of for when using React. [Check it out](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#supported-attributes).

```
<ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
      for="demo-menu-lower-left">
```

should be:

```
<ul className="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
      htmlFor="demo-menu-lower-left">
```

See the updated pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkmEzZ?editors=1111#anon-login).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know there was a htmlFor attribute.